# Types of data great for webscraping

Tags: data-request, web-crawling

I am a professional web-crawler and love scraping sites for potential data. However, I have recently hit a brick-wall on openly sourced websites with unique data that can be webscraped.

So I would like to gather a few ideas on data that would be great to scrape for the following reasons:

1. It's unique; It has not been scraped before, or minimal places to access this information.
2. Having a larger database for this data would be optimal for professionals in various fields to work with.

links to the websites to get the data would be great also!

Additional note:

- There is no specific region for this request; If the data can be found in various countries that would be a bonus!
- If the website does not like being web-crawled because the data is that much more difficult to grab, I am still happy to look into it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to find niche communities for an online video game that doesn't have an API, yet. (Check steamcharts.com for active players)

edit:
Since we have the same interest in webscraping niche/unique data, maybe we can combine forces and work on something together. Can I contact you offline?

Comment: I am always looking for someone to collaborate with! I have added my email to my profile page - you can contact me there and we can go from there :)